# Which database structure to use for website search engine

Tags: mysql, database, search-engine, database-normalization

### **EDIT** - Database Design C

Based on @duskwuff's solution. I believe this is also what is referred to as a **2NF** [normalised](http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php) database design.

My concern now is over the fact that there are duplicate column values in this design (the same Keyword like **Apricot** appears in multiple rows). As more values are added, will the database having *too many rows* impact speed or performance?

[image]
[image]

---

**Original post**

I am building a website search engine using PHP and mySQL. The goal is to search through a fruits catalogue with the ability to find fruits based on various search terms by the user.

For example, if a user searches for *'Fruit that starts with a'*, **Apples, Apricots** etc should come out. If a user searches for *'Fruits with a sweet taste'*, sweet tasting fruits like **Grape, Cranberry, Apricot** etc should come out.

In Design A, we have all the **fruit names listed as columns**. Under the columns would be the search terms that would lead into the fruit. So under **Apple**, you would find column values:  *'starts with a'* and *'sweet'*

In Design B, we have the fruit names listed instead as column values under a column titled **Keyword**. The search terms for each respective fruits are the respective column values of **SearchTerm1, SearchTerm2,** and so on.

**Which database design would perform better in terms of speed and scalability?**

---

### Database Design A

[image]
[image]

---

### Database Design B

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a many to many relationship. One fruit can have many associated search terms and one search term may have many fruits associated with it.

> Ex: {Apricot -> Sweet taste, starts with a, orange} and
>   {Sweet taste -> apricot, mango} etc.

***The way to do many to many relationship in databases is to introduce a table in the middle.***

Let there be a fruit table which has all the fruits. Introduce a synthetic primary key in both tables (if they don't have a naturally occurring primary key) to uniquely identify each row. Then create the middle table and for every pair of `<fruit, search term>` add a row in it. Create an index on the `<pk1, pk2>` of this table to keep it as fast as possible.

I found the following [image](http://en.tekstenuitleg.net/static/images/beertable.gif) after googling. It explains the idea.

[image]

In this table, a brand of beer can have multiple distributors and a distributor can be distributing multiple brands of beer. So we have the middle table `beer_distributor` which is essentially a table of the primary keys of the other two tables viz. `beer` and `distributor`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question @displayName, you even have photos :D I would like to ask, will there be any difference if I forgo the 1st and 3rd tables (of associating an **id** with the **beer/distributor**) and instead just have the middle table, associating the **beer** name to each **distributor**? It'd be like the Database Design C screenshot I posted in my edit above.

Comment: @blurgoon: In general it is not a good idea because when you would store some fruit in the `Fruit_table` you will not just store fruit's name. You may also store the place where it is found, its varieties and so on. So if you will try to store all that information in the middle table it will become not only very big (because of additional columns for each attribute in the side tables) but also will have repetitive information for all rows where a particular fruit is repeated. Same would happen for the  `Search_Term` table.

Comment: @blurgoon: What you are suggesting is called Denormalization which is a common practice when you want to improve the performance (in terms of speed up). You don't need to join now as you have stored joined tables already! But where you would just have M rows in table 1 and N rows in table 2, you will have M*N rows in table_1_2 with all columns storing only repeated information multiple times.

Comment: I get what you mean. But I'm not actually going to store the fruit details in the middle table. Hmm.. to explain it.. I would actually have a table like your 1st one, where all the fruit details will be saved and the table will have multiple columns. My middle table is actually just 2 columns: **FruitName** and **SearchTerm**. In this way, I'm actually using the **FruitName** as a primary key across both the middle table and my "fruit details" table.

Comment: @blurgoon: What attribute you use as PK is irrelevant as long as it does its job fine. After the PK is fixed, the design will be same as what I'm suggesting just with the new PKs from both tables constituting the middle table. And **FruitName** is PK in Fruit table and FK in the **FruitSearchTerm** table.

Comment: Ah okay, that's a relief then. Yep it will be. The most important thing as you said is to keep the middle table free of any other columns pertaining to the details of any of the two keys, because that would have repeated information of the fruit details, right?

Comment: @blurgoon: That's correct. Store only that information in the middle table which is needed to join the two tables AND the information that belongs to the *relationship* between the joined rows of those two tables.

Comment: In addition, (I just want to know whether my understanding of SQL is correct on this) the reason why I prefer to avoid assigning another ID to the Fruit is because when my users search and my script takes the things they have typed = $UserSearch, I would have to perform an addition query of finding the ID where SearchTerm = $UserSearch, before finding the relevant Fruit(s) in the middle table, as opposed to just being able to find the Fruit(s) straightaway in the middle table where SearchTerm = $UserSearch, which would have faster performance.

Comment: Am I right on ^ or is the additional performance gain really neligibele in favour of the neater organisation of using an ID?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93002/discussion-between-displayname-and-blurgoon).

Answer (score 1):

Both of these are poor database designs, because they are not properly [normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). The first design hard-codes names of objects, and the second one hard-codes a fixed number of attributes; both designs would be extremely cumbersome to query.

A more appropriate design would contain two columns - the fruit name and one search keyword for it - and one row for each pairing of fruits and keywords. An alternative would be to have one table with fruit names and ID numbers, and a second table pairing those ID numbers with search keywords.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Do you mean I have one column as Fruits, and the other column as SearchTerms? This also means that there will be multiple rows for a single fruit, am I right?

Also, why would it be a big deal if the objects or attributes are hard-coded, since more columns can always be added by the ALTER TABLE command?

Comment: Correct. Keep in mind that there is a limit to the number of columns in a table, and there is no way to reference "any column in the table" in a query. As a result, as you add columns, every query against the table becomes significantly more complex.

Comment: I added screenshots of the new structure in the original post. I also wrote my concern over the fact that due to the duplicate column values with this design, the database may have a huge number of rows over time. Will this affect performance in the long run?

Your introduction to normalisation has also helped me. I learnt a a fair bit tonight! Thank you :)

Comment: Lots of rows is okay! There's nothing wrong with that. As long as your database is properly indexed, it'll perform just fine.

Comment: Hey, I selected the other post as the answer instead. I really wish i could have selected both. But he gave me help outside the original scope of the question and I was appreciative of that.